# Complex Search Query in DB2 on zOS

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, db2

My UI page has a search form with 3 fields and the user should be able to search on one/all 3 forms in any given combinations. I am trying to come up with an SQL that works for all these scenarios instead of dynamically generating it.

In Oracle, I used to do something like the one below:

```
select * from USER_TABLE where (firstname is null OR firstname = :p_first ) AND 
 (:p_last is null OR lastname = :p_last ) AND  (:p_deptid is null OR deptid= :p_deptid )
```

I would like to do this same on DB2 on zOS. This is the closest I got it working so far.

```
select * from USER_TABLE where (COALESCE(:firstname, 'x') = 'x' OR firstname = :p_first ) AND 
 (COALESCE(:p_last, 'x') = 'x' OR lastname = :p_last) AND  (COALESCE(:p_deptid, 'x') = 'x' OR deptid= :p_deptid )
```

p_first, p_last and p_deptid are parameters with values entered by the user.

Eventually, I want to be able to use this query as NamedQuery in JPA.

**UPDATE: (updated with few more details as requested)**

There were few reasons why I had to come up with a slight modification to Oracle's version of the query.

1) @Turophile - When I use exactly the same SQL *(:p_first is null OR firstname = :p_first )*, I received the following error:

```
[Error Code: -417, SQL State: 42609]  A STATEMENT STRING TO BE PREPARED INCLUDES PARAMETER MARKERS AS THE OPERANDS OF THE SAME OPERATOR. SQLCODE=-417, SQLSTATE=42609, DRIVER=4.18.60. 2) [Error Code: -516, SQL State: 26501]  THE DESCRIBE STATEMENT DOES NOT SPECIFY A PREPARED STATEMENT. SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.18.60. 3) [Error Code: -514, SQL State: 26501]  THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

2) So, I came up with 'COALESCE' version of it. The SQL that I provided doesn't really work. It looks like DB2 is expecting the string length of both operand in  'COALESCE' to be equal or greater. That is, if I expect length of :p_deptid to be 5, the 2nd operand must be equal to or greater than 5. So, I needed to pad the 'x's in the above SQL.

```
select * from USER_TABLE where (COALESCE(:firstname, 'x') = 'x' OR firstname = :p_first ) AND 
     (COALESCE(:p_last, 'x') = 'x' OR lastname = :p_last) AND  (COALESCE(:p_deptid, 'xxxxxx') = 'xxxxxx' OR deptid= :p_deptid )
```

Otherwise, I get this error:

```
 [Error Code: -302, SQL State: 22001]  THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER 1 IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

I am totally new to DB2, based on my findings, the syntax seems to be very similar to Oracle but it looks the behavior is little different. I am also open to suggestions if there is any better way of doing this in DB2 world.

Comment: Why doesn't the Oracle code work?

Comment: Oracle code works, I am trying to get it to work on DB2 as well.

Comment: @CoderTR I think he meant "why doesn't that code you're using on Oracle work on DB2?" If you gave us an error message, we might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing if your parameters are null, not the column, for example, `(:p_first is null OR firstname = :p_first )`?

Comment: Thanks everyone for chiming in. I updated the original post with more details.

Comment: Forget that, the Oracle code is **wrong**, or you at least have a major typo; which parameters are you using again?  The general style works on DB2, though (having done it on the i).  You might be running into driver issues (some don't support named parameters, although I think you get better exceptions than that).  @Turophile is right about having typos in your second statement, too.  The other form to use there is `COALESCE(:param, column) = column`, but would likely prevent the use of indices (your original version is likely to optimize some of the comparisons out).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Oops, that was a typo in my Oracle SQL. I meant to use the params not the column names (updated now). I will also try `COALESCE(:param, column) = column` and let you know

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - your suggestion of using `COALESCE(:param, column) = column` worked in this case. can you add it as answer, i will approve it. And, big thanks to you and the others!

Comment: ...actually, I recommend you retry your original statement on DB2.  The error message is saying you're doing something like `:p_first is null OR :p_first = :p_first`.  Especially because you still have a typo in the Oracle version, which means you didn't copy from there in the first place...